# Detecting duplicate test coverage

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I've inherited a large Python code-base with very good test coverage (>90%); however, I know there are many places in which the code is covered by multiple tests.

- How does one go about detecting which tests overlap?
- What tools are available for detecting this?

I've done some searching and come up with the term "coverage density", which describes what I'm getting at; but I haven't found an obvious method or tool with which to tell me: for a given line of code, it's covered by these tests.

Corresponding /r/python question:
[Detecting duplicate test coverage](https://old.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/aitzfs/detecting_duplicate_test_coverage)

Comment: Welcome Erik.  May I ask what you mean by saying that code is covered by multiple tests?  Do the tests really test the same thing, or is it just that they happen to execute the same lines?  For example, if the code to test is a + b, you can have a test to check that it is an addition (rather than a subtraction), you have a test for underflow, one for overflow, one for type mismatches etc.  - all these would cover the same expression, but they would still not test the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`Coverage.py` added the concept of [contexts](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contexts.html) which allow recording in which context each of your lines of code was run during testing. It's main use case seems to be tracking which tests have code coverage for each line.

If you're using `pytest-cov` (which uses Coverage.py) then you can enable [this feature](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contexts.html) by adding `--cov-context=test` to your CLI call, e.g.

```bash
pytest --cov-context test --cov-report=html
```

And you can then see the results in the generated HTML report, but only if you've also added this config to `.coveragerc`:

```ini
[html]
show_contexts = True
```

If you're using `pyproject.toml` then you can rather add:

```ini
[tool.coverage.html]
show_contexts = true
```